# using Matlab, how to find the maximum value over a certain range?

Tags: matlab, max

i want to know the coding to find the maximum value, over a certain range.
i already coded like below.

```
f=f'
ac_yyyy_f=ac_yyyy_f'
[row,col] = ind2sub(size(ac_yyyy_f),find(ac_yyyy_f==max(ac_yyyy_f)))
```

but the problem is, sometimes the maximum value of Y axis choosen by my code is not what i want.
the X axis has the range of 0 to 100000 and i want the maximum between 20000 to 100000. the problem is sometimes the max value show up at the range of 0 to 20000. 
How can i figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `max()` function:

```
%let R be your range of values
R = [2 1 7 4];
[value, index] = max(R);
```

In the above example, `value` will be `7` and `index` will be `3`

For more info: http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a vector of random integers to stand in for your function output.

```
a = floor(rand(1,100000)*100);
[val, idx] = max(a(20000:100000));
```

You want to use the max function here to find the maximum value rather than find.
Now, the other part of the task is getting the max value from a certain part of your matrix. You can pass just a subset of a vector or matrix to a function by indexing it with a range of values. Note that `idx` gives you the position of `val` within `a(20000:100000)`. If you need the position within `a`, you need to use `idx+19999`.

Also, you should take a look at the matrix indexing reference—there are many different and fun ways to index a matrix—because indexing is one of the most important features of matlab.

Here's the reference for the max function:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html 
And the reference for indexing:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max` function with a subset of your array. It will return the maximum value, as well as the index where it is located. Be sure to correct the index it returns you based on your desired range. Like this:

```
%//create an array of 100,000 values to play with.
f=floor(rand(100000,1).*100);

%//find the max between f(20000) and f(100000)
[myMax, I] = max( f(20000:100000) );

%//correct the index based on where we started looking
%//for the max. Subtract 1 because it's MATLAB!
myIndex = I+20000-1;
```

This results in:

```
>> myMax
myMax =
    99
>> myIndex
myIndex =
       20045
>> f(myIndex)
ans =
    99
```